# Merging two indexed arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two indexed arrays that have been created by 2 loops:

**$questions**

```
Array ( 
    [10] => Yes 
    [11] => No 
    [12] => Yes 
    [13] => No 
    [14] => Yes 
    [15] => No 
)
```

**$comments**

```
Array ( 
    [10] => comment 
    [11] => comment 
    [12] => comment 
    [13] => comment 
    [14] => comment 
    [15] => comment 
)
```

How do I combine them so I get the below result and preserve the indexing:

```
Array ( 
    [10] => Yes, comment 
    [11] => No, comment 
    [12] => Yes, comment 
    [13] => No, comment 
    [14] => Yes, comment 
    [15] => No, comment 
 )
```

Looked at array_merge but that appends if the key is the same.

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

Looked at array_combine but that:

> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and
>   the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

I'm sure I need a third loop to 'combine' them but how can I do that?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the two arrays will have the same keys exactly?

Comment: yeah, its created by a form the comments and questions keys are hard coded

Comment: These are all great answers and i really appreciate the time spent to answer. Bubba is accepted as it provides more functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should provide you with a couple of options. It makes the logical assumption that the keys between $questions and $comments are in sync, and handles if there are some odd ones.

```
<?php
$questions = array(
    '10' => 'Yes',
    '11' => 'No',
    '12' => 'Yes',
    '13' => 'No',
    '14' => 'Yes',
    '15' => 'No',
    '16' => 'No'
 );
$comments = array(
    '10' => 'comment 10',
    '11' => 'comment 11',
    '12' => 'comment 12',
    '13' => 'comment 13',
    '14' => 'comment 14',
    '15' => 'comment 15',
    '17' => 'comment 17'
 );

$combinedAsArray = array();
$combinedAsString = array();

foreach ($questions as $key => $value){

    if (array_key_exists($key, $comments)){
        $combinedAsArray[$key] = array($value, $comments[$key]);
        $combinedAsString[$key] = "$value, {$comments[$key]}";
    }else{
        $combinedAsArray[$key] = array($value, null);
        $combinedAsString[$key] = "$value, ";
    }
}

foreach ($comments as $key => $value){
    if (! array_key_exists($key, $questions)){
        $combinedAsArray[$key] = array(null, $value);
        $combinedAsString[$key] = " , $value";
    }
}

print_r($combinedAsArray);
print_r($combinedAsString);
```

Comment: Did you put the <?php tag at the top?

Comment: this is awesome! but the questions and comments key is defined as $i. I see you have defined $key aswell. basically where do I put my $i key? after the $comments. like: $comments[$i]?? cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If you know that you'll have the exact same keys:

```
$new = array();
foreach($questions AS $key => $value) {
    $new[$key] = $value . ", " . $comments[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run an array map on this like so:

```
$merged_array = array_map(function($a, $b) {
    return $a . ', ' . $b;
}, $array1, $array2);
```

Or, if you don't want a concatenated string, but rather something like

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
        0 => 'Yes',
        1 => 'comment 10',
    )
    ...
)
```

You can pass `null` to array map like this:

```
$merged_array = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Your suggested technique does not preserve the keys as required by the OP.  https://3v4l.org/8CIXC

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays have the same indexes the solution could be:

```
foreach($first_array as $index => $value){
    $output_array[$index] = $value . ", " . $second_array[$index];
}
```